# ec2 auto scaling group with multiple port in target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I attached an EC2 auto scaling group to Target Group. However, It is only showing me one port, which is port 80.

My EC2 has multiple port from port 3000 - 3005. What is the correct way for me to register those port as well? Is it manually adding the instance from the target group as I did not find a way to do so in ec2 auto scaling

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> My EC2 has multiple port from port 3000 - 3005. What is the correct way for me to register those port as well?

You need **separate target groups** for each port you want to use.

Comment: Does this means that i have to create 4 EC2 auto scaling group from the same launch template and attached to load balancer? also where to create EC2 auto scaling group with different port configuration from port 80?

Comment: @vincentsty No. You can have same ASG. But you need to have separate target groups for each port. So basically you will associated 4 target groups with your ALB. Each TG will forward traffic to same instances, but to different ports.